Button weird background on over?
I'm using this Button:
<Button Name="buttonAttiva"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Margin="0,560,0,0">
    <TextBlock Text="Attiva" />

That's the style:
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource MahApps.Styles.Button}">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment"
            Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment"
            Value="Top" />
    <Setter Property="Width"
            Value="150" />
    <Setter Property="Height"
            Value="46" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
            Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
            Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="Background"
            Value="#81b3d4" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground"
            Value="#ffffff" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight"
            Value="Bold" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize"
            Value="18" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment"
            Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight"
            Value="Bold" />
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle"
            Value="{x:Null}" />
    <Setter Property="controls:ControlsHelper.MouseOverBorderBrush"
            Value="#000000" />
    <Setter Property="controls:ControlsHelper.FocusBorderBrush"
            Value="#000000" />
    <Setter Property="controls:ControlsHelper.FocusBorderThickness"
            Value="0" />
    <Style.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MahApps.Brushes.Gray7"
                         Color="#000000" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MahApps.Brushes.Gray8"
                         Color="#000000" />
    </Style.Resources>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsFocused"
                 Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background"
                    Value="#000000" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
                    Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                    Value="#000000" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                 Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background"
                    Value="#000000" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
                    Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                    Value="#000000" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsPressed"
                 Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background"
                    Value="#000000" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
                    Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                    Value="#000000" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

Which correctly display as:

But, when I over with mouse, a strange "gray" background appears:

How can i set the correct Orange Background?
Note, I'm using MahApps.Metro alongside, which could override some properties I guess?

Override the MahApps.Brushes.Gray8 resource that is used in the template:
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MahApps.Styles.Button}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MahApps.Brushes.Gray8" Color="Orange" />
    </Style.Resources>
...


Where do I see its used MahApps.Brushes.Gray8? So in future I can got where the style come/begin from?

You'll find the default templates on GitHub.

Yes but in this case how do you catch I'm using that specific property? :O where is set that Button use it on (some event I don't know) over? Wouldn't set the trigger/property a new color instead of overwrite a color variable?

note man: the -1 is not mine, so to speak :)

anyway: now over is ok, but when I "press" it, I can still see gray. Tried to override IsPressed, still no success. Also, once clicked, it seems to keep "selected", even if its not a toggle button (it should be "IsClicked" only for the moment where i click). Can you help also on this?

The "press" colour is defined by the MahApps.Brushes.Gray7 brush so you should define this one as well then.

It works, thanks! Now, why when clicked, until I click on another zone on the app, it keep "pressed"?

I cannot reproduce this based on the information your have posted. Your question contains a Button and this one is not "pressed" when you release the mouse.

I've update the question adding the complete Button style: once I just click with mouse (so mouse down/up, simple click) it remains black :O

Still not reproducible. Try to create a blank project and copy the code you have posted here into it and you'll see what I mean.

Its ok for now. I'll open a new question in the future if needed. Thanks

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
